# Single Regex for filtering roman numerals from the text files

Tags: regex, roman-numerals

I am stuck in between of a problem where only one pass of regular expression is allowed( some old hard code). I need the regex for roman numerals.

I have tried the standard one i.e. `^(?i)M*(D?C{0,3}|C[DM])(L?X{0,3}|X[LC])(V?I{0,3}|I[VX])$`, but the problem is it allows null(`''`) values also.

Is there any way around to check is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To require that at least one character must be present, you can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=.)` at the start of your regular expression:

```
^(?=.)(?i)M*(D?C{0,3}|C[DM])(L?X{0,3}|X[LC])(V?I{0,3}|I[VX])$
```

Another solution is to separately test that your string is not the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I like this one:

```
\b(?=[MDCLXVI]+\b)M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})\b
```